# How do I keep HTML from removing whitespaces?

Tags: html, text, formatting, tags, format

```
    <p>This    is    a    paragraph</p>
```

becomes

This    is    a    paragraph

but I want it to remain as is. Like

`This    is    a    paragraph`

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` - it is a non-breakable space.

For example:

```
<p>This&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;is&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;paragraph</p>
```

> A *non-breaking space* (also called *no-break space*, ***n***on-**b**reakable **sp**ace (***NBSP***), *hard space*, or *fixed space*) is a space character that prevents an automatic line break at its position. In some formats, including `HTML`, it also prevents consecutive whitespace characters from collapsing into a single space.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `&nbsp;`, you can use something like

`<p class="allspace">This    is    a    paragraph</p>`

```
.allspace { white-space: pre }
```

`white-space:pre` will format the html with spaces. This approach is better as it doesn't require multiple use of `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<p>This &nbsp;&nbsp; is &nbsp;&nbsp; a &nbsp;&nbsp; paragraph</p>
```

**& nbsp ;**

> Alternatively referred to as a fixed space or hard space, Non-Breaking
>   SPace (NBSP) is used in programming, and word processing to create a
>   space in a line that cannot be broken by word wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&nbsp;`. For example:

`Hello &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; World`

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use `<pre>` tag. This tag is used for indicating preformatted text. The code tag surrounds the code being marked up.

Browsers normally render pre text in a fixed-pitched font, with whitespace in tact, and without word wrap.

`<pre>hello         world</pre>`

Comment: This will give the text a font which makes it look like code. If you don't want it to look like code and still use the `<pre>` tag, you will have to use some CSS to change the font.